# Use variable declared in event handler of one function in another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

i have the following class

```
export default class{
  constructor({
  )} {
    this.myFoo();
    this.myBar();
  }

  myFoo() {
    if (myBool){
      ... 
    }
  }

  myBar() {
    this.myElement.on('my-trigger', (e, myBool) => {
      if(myBool){
        ... 
      }
    }
  }
```

I would like to use `myBool` brought in via the `myBar` jquery `.on()` handler
in a different function `myFoo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, You need to assign this value in scope of the class like:

```
export default class{
  constructor({
  )} {
    this.myFoo();
    this.myBar();
  }

  myFoo() {
    if (this.myBool){ 
      //now myBool is accessible via this.myBool
      ... 
    }
  }

  myBar() {
    var that=this;
    this.myElement.on('my-trigger', (e, myBool) => {

      if(myBool){
        that.myBool=myBool;
        ... 
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: hey yadav thanks for your answer, i will be happy to make it accepted answer, just want to see if theres alternatives/other methods

Comment: is `var that` a best practice for naming a temporary var like this? or should i name it after my class/component

Comment: i confirm that this worked for me. just wondering if theres cleaner, simpler solutions available for this in js

Comment: As per the general use case, this approach is fine. But in case of your specific requirements like when are both functions triggered, why are the variables needed - You can this of another solution.

Comment: @AkinHwan for the variable part, I thinks thats very subjective. People are using that=this approach from long time also.

Comment: i removed `var that=this`, and just set `this.myBool=myBool` and that worked as well